# Jquery Mobile - Script page navigation / Transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to trigger a page navigation/transition via code rather than a physical button using JQuery Mobile - I need a script to re-direct a page according to logic and would like it to navigate using the flow transition.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It is possible using `$.mobile.changePage('URL', { options } );`

Go through the [link](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

Answer (score 0):

`$.mobile.changePage('URL', { options } );` is deprecated now. http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

The proper way would be to use:

1. `$.mobile.navigate("#bar", {transition: "slide", info: "info about the #bar hash"});`
2. `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "target", {transition: "flow", changeHash: false, reload: true})`

Just thought I'd answer this question from what I've learnt from the other threads.
I don't have enough reputation to put up the rest of the links. Just search the code up on Google to find their respective StackOverflow threads.